# Primefaces upgrade 8 getScriptsToExecute equivalent

Tags: primefaces

Upgraded application from primefaces 5.3.6 to primefaces 8 version.What would be the equivalent of 
getScriptsToExecute method from RequestContext in PrimeFaces.current() instance.

Code in bean class:

```
final List<String> scriptsToExecute = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getScriptsToExecute();
scriptsToExecute.add("script1();");
scriptsToExecute.add("script2();");
scriptsToExecute.add("script3();");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("script3();");`

Please check the documentation next time: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/javaAPI and the migration guide: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

Comment: how I can get all scripts added in current request using Primefaces.current?@tandraschko

Comment: via PrimeRequestContext - but thats not an official API so dont expect that it wont change in the next versions :P